# Windows 10 - Background changes from 'Picture' to 'Solid Color' option randomly

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

On my computer which has Windows 10 64-bit, the background just changes to a solid color (whatever color I select in the 'Solid Color' option that's the color that it will change to when it randomly changes) from a picture I have set as the background.

Comment: Do you have the picture saved on your computer somewhere? or did you just use as background picture from a browser?

Comment: It's saved on my computer

Answer (score 1):

Generally Windows will drop from a wallpaper to a color when it drops the display quality. I can't find the wording for Windows 10. In Windows 7 it was when Aero would be turned off.

This generally happens when your display driver has crashed or a program is putting your computer in a low graphical state for resources (like launching a game).

You can check in Event Viewer (Click Start and type in `Event Viewer`) under `Windows Logs` then `Application`. If there is anything about the Display Adapter you might want to try to find a new driver.

Answer (score -1):

If you download a file from the internet it can become "blocked", as Windows thinks it can be malicious. If you click properties on the picture,

[image]

If you then click unblock, it will allow the picture to be set. Why it doesn't prompt you to unblock it when you change, I do not know...